# Is there an easy way to find all possible string modules (using the GAP package QPA)?

Tags: gap

I am trying to find all string modules of a given string algebra using the GAP package QPA. The aim is to have a list containing the strings corresponding to the string modules.

As an example:
For a quiver $Q$ with two vertices one loop $a$ at vertex 1 and one arrow $b$ from vertex 2 to vertex 1. Taking the string algebra $kQ/(a^2)$ I would like to get something like below, but I am not set on the formatting of the list strings:

strings := [$e_1, e_2, a, b, a^{-1}*b, a*b, b^{-1}*a*b$]